# Implications of Violation of Independence Assumption in ML Models

Tags: machine-learning

This is a somewhat broad question, but I'm having trouble finding a good answer anywhere. I know many ML models will impose an independence assumption in the data. But I'm having a hard time really understanding what the practical implications are if that independence assumption is violated. For linear/logistic regression, I get that it likely biases interpretation of the coefficients. But what about from a predictive performance standpoint? Does violating the independence assumption actually matter?

Answer (score 1):

In general, violation of independence assumptions results in residuals that are not actually maximal-entropy.  This could matter in terms of the applicability of known results regarding convergence to the "true" distribution being estimated.

Comment: Not sure if I totally follow. So it could hurt predictive power?

Comment: Yes.  Using a ML algorithm that assumes data are independent will fail to capture all of the details in a data set in which that assumption is violated.